# Gain access to child elements under HTMLCollection's

Tags: javascript

How do you gain access to child elements under HTMLCollection's children?

My code returns the following at: `console.log(iframeContent);`. I want to gain access to the children highlighted below and loop through/interrogate them.

[image]

Full code below:

```
function getPageStructure() {
  const iframe = document.getElementById('builder-showcase');
  const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  const iframeContent = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children;
  console.log(iframeContent);
}
```

Have tried the following:

```
console.log(iframeContent.children);
console.log(iframeContent[0].children);
```

but getting an undefined error message on both.

Comment: (These are not children of the HTMLCollection, these are children of the first element in your collection, which is what you are looking at here under the `0` key.)

Comment: @RyanWilson I get `undefined` when I try `console.log(iframeContent.children);`

Comment: have you tried @04FS' suggestion?
`iframeContent[0].children`

Comment: Yup, I have tried it before posting the question. I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const iframeContent = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children;
```

already grabs `.children`, so logging `console.log(iframeContent.children);` won´t work.

Use `console.log(iframeContent)` instead.

If `console.log(iframeContent)` gets the array including the children you can use `console.log(iframeContent[0])` and vice versa to select the `div` elements inside `iframeContent`.

You can also use `iframeContent.forEach(child => console.log(child))` to log all the children of `iframeContent`.

Comment: Thanks. This works but how do I access the children of the children?

Comment: For `iframeContent.forEach(child => console.log(child))`, I get the error message `TypeError: iframeContent.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Does `console.log(iframeContent)` log the whole array you are trying to target?